# How to extend selection in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, xterm, selection

In a terminal I can select a single line, double clicking with the Left Mouse Button.

With xterm, I can extend that selection clicking with the Right Mouse Button in the place I want to extend it. Then can I paste the whole selection with the Middle Mouse Button or paste it in other application.

In gnome-terminal, it seems I can extend the selection clicking with the Left Mouse Button, but holding at the same time the Shift key. Visually, it seems the selection is done, but when clicking with the Middle Mouse button or pasting in other application, I only get the primary single line selection.

How can I get the whole selection under gnome-terminal? Is it possible to use selections in gnome-terminal as xterm does?

Cheers, Tomas.

Comment: Works fine here (Arch64bit/Gnome3). The difference is that I have to left click three times to select a line (both in xTerm and gnome-terminal). Then hold SHIFT and another left click to select another line. Pasting then with the middle button works fine both in documents and gnome-terminal. So whatever it is it's related to your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `xterm`, but as far as selecting content within `gnome-terminal`, I just drag to select. In other words, I left-click and keep the left mouse button pressed while dragging to select what I want. I then release the left mouse button and single-click the right mouse button. From the context menu that appears, I choose "copy". I can then paste that into a text editor or wherever with Ctrl+V. Multiple lines can be copied and pasted this way.

(I hope I've understood your question correctly.)